# JPA 2.0 Caching and Insert queries

Tags: caching, jpa, entity, on-duplicate-key

***Problem Description***

The application was upgraded to use Eclipselink as the JPA 2.0  provider and running to series of Duplicate Key exceptions. The application receives huge traffic and does lot of DB inserts using the entities.

Recently the app has been upgraded to use EclipseLink( JPA2.0) as the JPA provider. Prior to this, the app was using JPA 1.0. The entity is listed below(LoggerEntity) was written for JPA 1.0 and we continued using it for JPA 2.0. But we are experiencing lots of duplicate key exceptions.

I read in a post that JPA 1.0 does not provide shared cache but  Eclipselink by default provides shared cache.

**Question**
****1)****  How does the insert query work in a shared cache mode. Is it that the JPA framework is caching the insert query  resulting in duplicate key exception. Am asking this because without the shared cache mode in JPA 1.0 this entity class works fine

**2)** Since currently the app is upgraded to use JPA 2.0 , should i set the shared cache mode on the entity like

```
@Cache(isolation=CacheIsolationType.ISOLATED, expiry=0, alwaysRefresh=true)
```

to suit the JPA 2.0 version. Will this work ? 
Am more interested in the way the insert query is cached in JPA 2.0 and somehow resulting in duplicate key exceptions.

**The entity class which we currently use from JPA 1.0 version without shared cache mode**

```
 @Entity 
    @Table(name="LOGTRANSACT") 
    public class LoggerEntity implements Serializable {
        @EmbeddedId
        private LogEntityPK pk;

        @Column(name="TRS_CRT_DT")
        private Timestamp trsCrtDt;

        @Column(name="TRS_CRT_TM")
        private Timestamp trsCrtTm;

        @Column(name="PRC_NA")
        private String prcNa;

        @Column(name="TRS_DAT_TE")
        private String trsDatTe;

        @Column(name="TRS_LOG_RSN_TE")
        private String trsLogRsnTe;

        @Column(name="REC_UDT_TS")
        private Timestamp recUdtTs;

        @Column(name="SER_NA")
        private String serNa;

        @Column(name="CUS_INF_RQT_NR")
        private String cusInfRqtNr;

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public LogEntity() {
            super();
        }
```

And persisting like this

```
              userTransaction.begin();
              LoggerEntity entity = new LoggerEntity();
              LogEntityPK pk = new LogEntityPK()
              ..
              ..
              ..
              entityManager.persist(entity); 
              userTransaction.commit();



@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if ( ! (o instanceof LogEntityPK)) {
            return false;
        }
        LogEntityPK other = (LogEntityPK) o;
        return this.calIdNr.equals(other.calIdNr)
            && this.trsTypCd.equals(other.trsTypCd);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * prime + this.calIdNr.hashCode();
        hash = hash * prime + this.trsTypCd.hashCode();
        return hash;
    }
```

Comment: How is `LogEntityPK` compound primary key defined?

Comment: 'code' @Embeddable
public class LogEntityPK implements Serializable {
 @Column(name="CAL_ID_NR")
 private String calIdNr;

 @Column(name="TRS_TYP_CD")
 private String trsTypCd;

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 public LogEntityPK() {
  super();
 }

 }

Comment: `code` @Embeddable
public class LogEntityPK implements Serializable {
 @Column(name="CAL_ID_NR")
 private String calIdNr;

 @Column(name="TRS_TYP_CD")
 private String trsTypCd;

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 public LogEntityPK() {
  super();
 }

 }`code`

Comment: Does `LogEntityPK` implement equals and hashCode methods? As far as I know they are required.

Comment: yes they implement equals and hashcode. updated the main post

Comment: `code` @Override
 public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (o == this) {
   return true;
  }
  if ( ! (o instanceof LogEntityPK)) {
   return false;
  }
  LogEntityPK other = (LogEntityPK) o;
  return this.calIdNr.equals(other.calIdNr)
   && this.trsTypCd.equals(other.trsTypCd);
 }

 @Override
 public int hashCode() {
  final int prime = 31;
  int hash = 17;
  hash = hash * prime + this.calIdNr.hashCode();
  hash = hash * prime + this.trsTypCd.hashCode();
  return hash;
 }